# ThreadPoolTimer doesn't call method periodically

Tags: c#, uwp, async-await

In my UWP project, I have created a button to start a `ThreadPoolTimer`. It shall have a period of 45sec.

I used the following code:

```
public void Start_Click(Object sender,RoutedEventArgs e) 
    {
        TimeSpan period = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TIntervall);

        ThreadPoolTimer PeriodicTimer = ThreadPoolTimer.CreatePeriodicTimer((source) =>
        {
            WriteDB();
            Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High,
            () =>
            {
            });
        },
        period,
        (source) =>
        {
            Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High,
            () =>
            {
        });
        });
    }
```

The method `WriteDB()`is a synchronous function which connects to a DB and inserts a line; and it displays in Debug.WriteLine the current timestamp.

My issue: The displayed timestamps are not 45secs away from each other, but between 1 and 40 secs.

Why? Do I need to create some `await`s ?

EDIT (Added code for WriteDB()):

```
private Boolean WriteDB()
{
string connectionString = "XXXXX";
Boolean ret = false;

try
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        string hum = "70";
        string temp = "23";
        string nnn = DateTime.Now.ToString();

        string SetQuery = "INSERT INTO dbo.measure VALUES ('1'," + "N'" + nnn + "'" + "," + Convert.ToSingle(temp, new CultureInfo("en-US")) + "," + Convert.ToSingle(hum, new CultureInfo("en-US")) + ",N'TestDevice');";


        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Query: " + SetQuery);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Humidity at " + nnn + " = " + hum);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Temperature: " + nnn + " = " + temp);

        conn.Open();
        if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = SetQuery;
                int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
    ret = true;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);

}
return ret;
}
```

Comment: What's in your `TIntervall` ?

Comment: `TIntervall` is a `const` and is equal to 45.

Comment: Can you post the code for `WriteDB()` and your sample output that shows the timestamps?

Comment: I edited my initial post and added the required code.

Answer (score 0):

Argh... I found the reason for my issue (rather stupidity):
I clicked multiple times on the button...

Is it really the case that for each click a dedicated thread with its own timer is being launched?

Comment: Yes. You can make `PeriodicTimer` a class field instead of a local variable and then check for`null` before creating a new one